# How to get a RMSE value

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, linear-regression

I already fit the equation. Now I want the RMSE value

```
q3_1=data1[['bedrooms', 'bathrooms', 'sqft_living', 'sqft_lot', 'floors', 'zipcode']]

q3_2=data1[['bedrooms', 'bathrooms', 'sqft_living', 'sqft_lot', 'floors','zipcode','condition','grade','waterfront','view','sqft_above','sqft_basement','yr_built','yr_renovated',              
'lat', 'long','sqft_living15','sqft_lot15']]

reg = LinearRegression()

reg.fit(q3_1,data1.price)

reg.fit(q3_2,data1.price)
```

I am not able to proceed from here. I need the RMSE value in both the cases.

Comment: Which framework do you use?

Comment: I am using google colab

Comment: If you are interested in manually calculating Root Mean Squared Error (RMSE) first (A) calculate the regression errors as (fit - price), then (B) square those errors, and (C) find the mean (average) value of those squares, and finally (D) take the square root of that mean value. The RMSE is very similar to "average magnitude of error" and is often used for that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

As I can understand, you are using TensorFlow on Google Colab.

I don't know exactly what is your `LinearRegression` object, but I suppose that it is a Keras model with a single node.

Hence, I have a question, how do you train the same model (your `reg` instance) with datasets with different schema -- one with 6 columns, the other with 16?

By the way, during training/fitting, keras is able to give you the MSE of your epoch, as well as a validation MSE if you provide a validation dataset. Finally, you can use the [`evaluate`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#evaluate) method which:

> Returns the loss value & metrics values for the model [...]

Just use the "mean_squared_error" metric.

---

### Edit

As you are using `scikit-learn` you have to take care of the metric yourself.
You can use the [`predict`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.predict) method to get the predictions from your trained model against a dataset.
Then, there is the [`mean_squared_error`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.mean_squared_error.html) metric which is straighforward to use.

```py
train_x, train_y = data1.features[:-100], data1.price[:-100]
test_x, test_y = data1.features[-100:], data1.price[-100:]

reg = LinearRegression()
reg.fit(train_x, train_y)

predictions = reg.predict(test_x)
mse = sklearn.metrics.mean_squared_error(test_y, predictions)
print("RMSE: %s" % math.sqrt(mse))
```

Comment: I am using scikit learn library. Can u show me how to do using scikit learn libarary